# Canadian toll-free numbers are labeled as US

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Canadian toll-free numbers (+1 888 ...) are labeled as 'US' in Calendar UI when added as phone entry point to conference data like so...

```
ConferenceDataService.newEntryPoint()
  .setEntryPointType(ConferenceDataService.EntryPointType.PHONE)
  .setRegionCode('CA')
  .addFeature(ConferenceDataService.EntryPointFeature.TOLL_FREE)
  .setUri('tel:+1888xxx')
  .setPin('123')
```

The problem is that the area code exists in both countries, but why is the passed region code ignored?

Comment: May actually be a bug - try to take a look if the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%20phone) has the issue submitted (I did not see anything similar, though) and create a new one, then post as a self-answer here so others affected can get help and star your issue

Comment: I've not used this service myself and I agree with @OlegValter- could be a bug. Just out of curiosity, have you tried `CAN` instead?

Comment: @OlegValter thanks for the hint! I filed an issue but was redirected to the Calendar's feedback form. I fear this is a dead end so I can't say anything on how to get that solved.

Comment: This is strange - can you provide the link to the issur you created? Google does not usually redirect devs from issue tracker

Comment: sure... https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/171982450

Comment: @SourabhChoraria no, I didn't try 'CAN' yet but I'll check that...